Building gradle app fails when com.google.firebase:firebase-bom is updated to 32.6.0
I'm trying to upgrade com.google.firebase:firebase-bom from version 29.0.0 to 32.6.0 and I ran into this error:

/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/467bb9d3066a57ac5f94cf19b169a6ba/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.5.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

Does this version have a specific gradle version required?
At the moment, my gradle version is 7.3.3
and kotlin dependencies versions are as below:
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.21

I've tried deleting gradle cache and even the .gradle folder itself but nothing seems to work.
What could be the issue and how may I solve this? Any input is appreciated.

you need to update gradle version as well

@BobSmith aa i see. To gradle 8?

Yes try with Android Gradle Plugin 8.3.0

@BobSmith Alright will try it out. Thanks for your help.

Check project level build.gradle > kotlin version make it 1.9 from 1.6. and if you get any other error edit your question. Check this for more information https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details

@BobSmith i don't have kotlin version set, just the 2 plugins above. If I do set it to 1.6, the error is still occurring. Trying to upgrade to gradle 8

Can you post project level build.gradle and app level build.gradle file ?

@Bob hey your answer is correct. It needs minimum AGP 8.2.0 which requires Gradle 8 for this unfortunately. Please write it as an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer for this question. Thanks

Below project is configured with AGP version 8.2.2
1. Check project level build.gradle > kotlin version make it 1.9 from 1.6.
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2' //updated gradle
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.0" //updated kotlin version

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

2. App level build.gradle update java version
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.toString()
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    namespace 'com.test.test'
}

dependencies {
    
     // ..... your other dependencies

}

3. Go to your project > gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
update gradle version
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

Make desired changes if you want to upgrade for higher version.
And if you get any other error edit your question. Check this for more information
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details

AGP compatibility with Android Studio

Gradle plugin details - https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle
